# data is not inserted in mysql database from php code using wamp server

Tags: php, mysql

i am writing a simple code of php to insert data in mysql database using wamp server. but data in not insert in the database . can anyone tell me what is wrong in my code. `    I am writing a simple code of php to insert data in mysql database using wamp server. but data in not insert in the database . can anyone tell me what is wrong in my code.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','my_first_database');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $city=$_POST['city'];
    if(mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO student_record(Name,Fname,city) array_values( ('$name','$fname','$city'))")){
        echo "data submitted";
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <br><input type="text" name="fname">
    <br><input type="text" name="city">
    <br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You assigned POST to variables. Don’t use array_values, just use VALUES and use the variable names as you have them.

Also remove the extra set of parenthesis from around your variable values.

Try:

```
if(mysqli->query($con, "
INSERT INTO 
    student_record(Name, Fname, city)
VALUES
    ('$name', '$fname', '$city')")) {...//rest of Code
```

The whole code should look like this:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "yourpassword", "my_first_database");

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $city=$_POST['city'];

    if (mysqli->query($con, "
        INSERT INTO 
            student_record(Name, Fname, city) 
        VALUES
            ('$name', '$fname', '$city')")) {

    echo "data submitted";
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="name">
<br>
<input type="text" name="fname">
<br>
<input type="text" name="city">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I’m trusting your column names  are correct. If they are you should be more consistent with them. Really you should follow PSR, but if you don’t follow PSR at least be consistent. Having Name and the city are different. It should be either Name and City or name and city; I’d prefer the former- just be consistent. =)

Comment: no you made it worse `('$name', '$fname', '$city')`

Comment: Midnight, tired, typing on phone- I should probably go to bed. =P

Comment: @smith On iOS- I’ve never even noticed it defaults to a curly quote. Had to hold it to change it each time. That sucks. Thanks for pointing that out. Will have to see if I can remedy that somehow.

Comment: @StatikStasis i have changed my code as you say and column names are right . But its still not working . please help me .

Comment: @nabeel Try what I have added above. Another tip- you should not use your db root user but instead use another user with proper permissions set to limit risk.